# Advantages of useAppDispatch / How to use useAppDispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

Given the official article of RTK:
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#getting-the-dispatch-type

But does it provide any advantage utilizing `useAppDispatch`?

Is there any different from this...

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
...
dispatch(increment(42))
```

to this?

```
const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
...
dispatch(increment(42)) // am I missing something important here?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal Redux `Dispatch` type has no knowledge of any middleware your store might have active - and middleware can change your dispatch result.

So with normal dispatch (`AppDispatch`), you would get

```
const myThunk = () => () => {  return 5 }
const result = dispatch(myThunk())
// result is of type `() => number`
```

with a correct dispatch you would get the real result thought:

```
const myThunk = () => () => {  return 5 }
const result = dispatch(myThunk())
// result is of type `number`
```

Comment: But for synchronous action creators created by slices, I'm not seeing any different through.

Comment: Correct, those don't need any middleware. But as soon as you add any middleware that modifies `dispatch`, you should have the `AppDispatch` instead of `Dispatch`. And you will never know what you add in the futures or how you might want to use thunks, so it is best to go with the "correct" stuff from the start, especially if it's only a one-time-setup thing.